# Case statements with Join on lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-server-2012

I have a big table with some columns having lookup values. I want to create a description column for each lookup column and populate them with description from lookup table.

Here is one example

#### main table

```
select id1, id2, id3 from idtable;
```

| id1 | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |

#### look up table

```
select code, id, desc from lookup;
```

| code | id | desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 1 | id1-desc1 |
| id2 | 2 | id2-desc2 |
| id2 | 3 | id2-desc3 |
| id3 | 3 | id3-desc3 |
| id3 | 4 | id3-desc4 |

I want the result set like:

| id1 | id1desc | id2 | id2desc | id3 | id3desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id1-desc1 | 2 | id2-desc2 | 3 | id3-desc3 |
| 1 | id1-desc1 | 3 | id2-desc3 | 4 | id3-desc4 |

What is the best and most efficient way to write the SQL solution for this?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Hint: `LEFT JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`...

Comment: Hi I am still trying to figure out how to accept the answers. This is a great community and  ahsla lways helped me. can you please guide where is the option to select "accept answer"?

Comment: Thank you, @stu! I can vote up/dow now. Can you confim if you see my votes. Thanks!

Comment: I got it. Thanks for correcitng me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three joins:

```sql
SELECT id1, l1.desc AS id1desc,
       id2, l2.desc AS id2desc,
       id3, l3.desc AS id3desc
FROM   idtable i
JOIN   lookup l1 ON id1 = l1.id
JOIN   lookup l2 ON id2 = l2.id
JOIN   lookup l2 ON id3 = l3.id
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik! Its a table with 100 columns and 500k rows and I was thinking if there is a better way than doing joins so many times.

Comment: @SQLSERVERDAWG I'd gently suggest that if you have 100 identical columns then you have a serious denormalization issue